# using svg stroke as clip path

Tags: html, css, svg, clip-path

I want to have an hollow circle as clip path, but when i apply the mask the region covered is the whole circle. There is any method to obtain this effect? (Like a border of a border-radius:50% div)

```
<svg class="svg-defs">
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clipping">
            <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

clip-path: url(#clipping);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have discovered, a `<clipPath>` only uses the fill of the shapes.

Use a `<mask>` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
   <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: i cant use the stroke as clip path..